# Why i can't push my JSX code to the head element?

Tags: reactjs, json, frontend, babeljs, jsx

I am trying to learn ReactJS and I have taught JSX by using Babel. I did like the video iIlearned but I have some problems. the engine doesn't push my code to the head element so I don't see anything happen. who can help me with this? thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5yZd.png)
this is my code:

i hope someone can help me and i am very grateful for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your ul element in brackets, like below:

```
const ul = (
  <ul>
    <li>JavaScript</li>
    <li>ReactJS</li>
  </ul>
)
```

Comment: it doesn't work, something wronged so the main screen don't display anything

Comment: its works for me, try use this in your react and babels cdn <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

Comment: first you can try to remove your src="hochanh.js" in your script tag, just write type="text/babel" only in your script tag like: <script type="text/babel">

Comment: okee i'm done thank you very much<33